# JUnit can't be found despite being defined in the pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-8, pom.xml

The title pretty much says it all. I have a project which uses Junit for testing, and upon building the project (IntelliJ) I'm getting the error

```
Error:(3, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
```

*Have you added the dependency in the pom.xml?*

Yes.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

*Is the scope correct?*
Yes. My testing class is in the folder "test".

*Have you tried forcing the version?*

Yes, doesn't change anything.

*Have you tried rebuilding/cleaning the project?*

Also yes, doesn't change anything either.
I'm really getting desperate, I even tried reinstalling Intellij completely, but it still doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help? What did I/ am I missing here?

Comment: first you have to check if maven *downloaded*  your `junit` jar in the project like you've it in the pom.xml. Look in your IntelliJ if the `junit jar` is in your classpath installed. have you checked it ?

Comment: @arthur yes, IntelliJ is showing junit under external libraries, if that's what you're asking

Comment: can you unfold the `junit-jar `to see if there are classes and package in it ? if it is not empty?

Comment: Have you tried running your tests from the command line, just to rule out the possibility that there's something wrong with the IDE's config?

Comment: @arthur it seems like maven isnt downloading the dependencies automatically, despite the pom.xml being configured. reimporting doesnt help either, why could that be the case?

Comment: @GeorgeAristy I don't think it should be relevant since it's a compilation error. but yes, doesn't work either

Comment: you'll have to check what it is configured in IntellJ. to force IntelliJ to re- import all your maven-depedencies, please do `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`A` , then input "reimport", you will find the "Reimport All Maven Projects"

Comment: @arthur ok now I'm really confused. I just deleted the project and reimported it with maven, and it worked. I even checked the "import maven projects automatically" box. All is good, testing works. If I close the project and reopen it, it says "non-managed pom.xml found" and the SDK isn't defined either. If I do this, the error occurs again. Reimporting all maven projects doesn't help either.

Comment: @just_deko which version of Intellij are using ? and it is community and enterprise ??

Comment: @arthur Enterprise, but I had the same problem with community. Both the newest ones.

Comment: @just_deko woud you please consider using older versions of intelliJ? It might be an interal bug.

Comment: @arthur wouldn't it be a general and widely known occurence in that case?

Comment: which version of junit are you using ?

Comment: @AbelRoussi the newest one, look at the pom dependency

Comment: @just_deko If I were in your place, I will first check my local repository to see if there is the junit in there, if not I'll check if I have a proxy settings. Finaly you can compare your project with the [junit5-samples on the officiel repo of junit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-maven-consumer)

Comment: Can't really elaborate enough for it to be an answer, but moving the project to a non-cloud-backed repository worked for me.